# How to add author's posts link (HTML + PHP) inside a function to output it

Tags: php, functions

I have this function on a theme which is a bit of code for a slider:

```
function get_article_slide( $title, $excerpt, $link_article, $url_image, $title_length, $alt_image = 'Alternative text' )
    {
        // Parameters
        if ( strlen( $title ) > $title_length ) $title = mb_substr( $title, 0, $title_length ) . "...";

        $title = apply_filters( 'prlx_slide_title', $title, get_the_title() );

        // Slide output
        $outputSlide  = "<div class='da-slide'>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "<div class='da-img-wrapper'><div class='da-img'><img src='".$url_image."' alt='".$alt_image."' /></div></div>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "<div class='da-text-wrapper'>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "<h2>".$title."</h2>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "<p>".$excerpt."</p>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "<a href='".$link_article."' class='da-link'>" . __( 'Read more', 'wp-parallax-content-slider' ) . "</a>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "</div>"."\n";
        $outputSlide .= "</div>"."\n";

        $outputSlide = apply_filters( 'prlx_slide_content', $outputSlide, $this );

        return $outputSlide;
    }
```

I discovered that this is what outputs the html for the slider, and now I'm trying to add an extra HTML + php to it but I don't know how to do it. I tried a couple of ways based on these outputs but it didn't work, here's the code I want to add/implement to this function right next the `<div class='da-text-wrapper'>`:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line right after the one you mention:

`$outputSlide .= '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . '">' . get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ) . '</a>';`

Note change of the_author_meta() to get_the_author_meta(). the_author_meta() will echo the result, whereas get_the_author_meta() just gets the result which is added to the $outputSlide variable and returned as the last line in the function.